# Google API to get all public & private photos +1'd by the currently authenticated user

Tags: google-api, google-plus-one, google-photos

I've been cheerfully plus-one-ing all the good photos that my family and I share with each other (shared only to my family circle, not public). I assumed that at some point I'd be able to retrieve all +1'd photos and create a physical family album... however it looks like there's no way through the Google+ UI to actually retrieve that information:

https://plus.google.com/+RobertoTyley/posts/i4bqxxSpceq

Is there any *API* that allows you to retrieve the currently authenticated user's +1s?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell there is no way to see what you have +1ed you can see your comments so if you had commented on all the posts.

[Activites list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list) only appears to return **public** posts,  being that its public only its no help to you.  That and its posts and not +1s

[Comments list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/comments/list) is of no help either even if you had commented and not +1ed because its comments on a post and not a picture and you would have to know the post.

But the thing is that pictures are also accessible via the [Picasa Web Albums Data API](https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#ListAlbumPhotos)  I don't have any experience with this API, but just scanned the documentation a bit.  It does let you request albums and check the comments on the album it may also show a +1 on it I don't know.

IMO Google+ api is probably a dead end I don't think it has what you need.  I would try digging around the Picasa api see if you cant use that instead.